# Does blackberry provide a css library for custom web apps like iPhones UIKit?

Tags: css, web-applications, blackberry

does anyone know if Blackberry provides a set of standard css to create web apps on a blackberry browser?  I guess blackberry equivalent of what the iPhone provides to make iPhone web apps look customized for an iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I know of but on RIM's site there are some documents about the Blackberry Browser, http://na.blackberry.com/eng/support/docs/subcategories/?userType=21&category=BlackBerry+Browser

You can also check out a PDF they have on CSS for Blackberry, http://na.blackberry.com/eng/deliverables/5683/CSS_Reference.pdf

And they have a PDF on design guidelines when developing for Blackberry browser which might be handy, http://na.blackberry.com/eng/deliverables/4305/BlackBerry_Browser-4.6.0-US.pdf